# Python Pandas: DataFrame as a Lookup Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup-tables

This is a preprocessed DataFrame, with columns representing frequency and success values for specific column. For example: Column `A` is associated with `FREQ_A` and `SUCCESS_A` respectively.

```
   A  B  Gold  FREQ_A  SUCCESS_A  FREQ_B  SUCCESS_B
0  1  B     0       1       0.00       1       0.00
1  2  A     1       1       0.01       1       0.01
```

I have another DataFrame, like the following:

```
   A  B
0  1  A
1  2  B
```

Now I want to add the associated frequency and success columns (`FREQ_*` and `SUCCESS_*`, `* : {A,B}`), looking up the values from the preprocessed DataFrame. An important observation is that the preprocessed DataFrame has an identical set of (non freq/success) columns, but not a complete set of keys. (See row `2`, `A:3` and `B:C` are not located in the preprocessed frame)

For example:

The first row in the dataframe, has values `A = 1, B = A`, so:

`FREQ_A` will take the value of the original dataframe of `FREQ_A` where `A == 1`

and

`FREQ_B` will take the value of the original dataframe of `FREQ_B` where `B == A`

**Ideal output**

```
   A  B  FREQ_A  SUCCESS_A  FREQ_B  SUCCESS_B
0  1  A       1       0.00       1       0.01
1  2  B       1       0.01       1       0.00
```

**Test case**

```
   A  B
0  1  A
1  2  B
2  1  C
3  4  A
```

Comment: can't you just call `drop_duplicates()` on the above to achieve what you want?

Comment: In this example, yes! But row `1` could be `1 1 B`, which isn't in the original Dataframe - I think will update the second DataFrame to make this non-trivial

Comment: I don't understand your comment how does `1 1 B` map to your columns? Can you edit your question

Comment: I will, sorry if it isn't clear. `Index = 1, A = 1, B = B`, would output `FREQ_A = 3, SUCCESS_A = 0.006667, FREQ_B = 1, SUCCESS_B = 0.010000`

Comment: now it got even more confusing... what is/are the joining condition(s)?

Comment: I'm going to re-do the question now!

Comment: Have updated the question, sorry for confusion.

Comment: joining by index or by column `A` is not an option, i guess?

Comment: Exactly, that is the issue. The actual DataFrame I want to perform this on has `500,000+` rows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
 'A': [1, 2],
 'B': ['B', 'A'],
 'FREQ_A': [1, 1],
 'FREQ_B': [1, 1],
 'Gold': [0, 1],
 'SUCCESS_A': [0.0, 0.01],
 'SUCCESS_B': [0.0, 0.01]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': ['A', 'B']})

result = (df2
          .merge(df1[['A', 'FREQ_A', 'SUCCESS_A']], on='A')
          .merge(df1[['B', 'FREQ_B', 'SUCCESS_B']], on='B'))
>>> result
   A  B  FREQ_A  SUCCESS_A  FREQ_B  SUCCESS_B
0  1  A       1       0.00       1       0.01
1  2  B       1       0.01       1       0.00
```

**EDIT**

For an arbitrary dataframe:

```
result = pd.concat(
    [df2, pd.concat([df2[[col]].merge(
                         df1[[col, 'FREQ_' + str(col), 'SUCCESS_' + str(col)]], 
                         on=col, how='left').iloc[:, 1:] 
                     for col in df2], axis=1)], 
    axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks!! And I can merge in a loop with a list of cols instead of `on='A'`? Would this effect quadratic copying issues with the call to merge?

Comment: `for col in df.columns: df = df.merge(df_lookup[[col, 'FREQ_'+str(col), 'SUCCESS_'+str(col)]], how='left')` This actually takes care of inserting nan values and maintaining original rows in second DataFrame

Comment: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. Dang. I've just seen your updated solution, appending to a list then concatenating simultaneously should avoid quadratic copying of merge. I will try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly for the new test case in the question

Comment: Incorrect results, for the test case I've added it, in row 2, it retrieves results for `df['B'] = C` which isnt in the lookup table, and in row 3 it doesn't retrieve values for `df['B'] = A`, which is in the lookup table

Comment: I need to add `how='left'`.  The default value for merge is 'inner'

Comment: for a really efficient solution,  just found that you can merge with `df1.drop_duplicates([col])`. This solved the out of memory issues I was having (In your solution this would replace `df1`)