# pandas lookup with long and nested conditions

Tags: python, pandas, lookup, lookup-tables

I want to perform a lookup in a dataframe via pandas. But It will be created by a series of nested if else statement similar as outlined [Pandas dataframe add a field based on multiple if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733893/pandas-dataframe-add-a-field-based-on-multiple-if-statements)
But I want to use up to `13` different variables. This seems to pretty soon result in chaos. Is there some notation or other nice feature which allows me to specify such long and nested conditions in pandas?
So far `np.where()` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html might be my best option.

Is there a shortcut if I would only match for equality in all conditions?

Am I forced to write out each conditional filter? Ir could I just have a single expression which is choosing a (single) lookup value which is produced.

Edit Ideally I would not want to match

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
```

for each value ie. `13*` number of categorical levels (lets assume `7`) would be a lot of different values; especially, `if df.loc[df['fist'] == some_value][df['second'] == otherValue1]` combination of conditions occur i.e. they are all chained.

## edit

A minimal example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ageGroup': [1, 2, 2, 1],
                 'first2DigitsOfPostcode': ['12', '23', '12', '12'],
                 'valueOfProduct': ['low', 'medum', 'high', 'low'],
               'lookup_join_value': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']})
```

defines the lookup table which was generated by a sql query grouping by all the columns and aggregating the values (so due to the Cartesian product all. value combinations should be represented in the lookup table.

A new record could look like

```
new_values = pd.DataFrame({'ageGroup': [1],
                     'first2DigitsOfPostcode': ['12'],
                     'valueOfProduct': ['low']})
```

How can I sort of automate the lookup of all the conditions assuming all conditions require an match by equality (if this makes it easier.

I found

- pd.lookup [Vectorized look-up of values in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893227/vectorized-look-up-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe) which seems to work for a single column / condition
- maybe a merge could be a solution? [Python Pandas: DataFrame as a Lookup Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36522162/python-pandas-dataframe-as-a-lookup-table), but that not really produce the desired lookup result.

### edit 2

The second answer seems to be pretty interesting. But

```
mask = df.drop('lookup_join_value', axis=1).isin(new_values)
print(mask)
print(df[mask])
print(df[mask]['lookup_join_value'])
```

will unfortunately just return NaN for the lookup value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I better know what you're after, a dataframe merge **is** likely a much better choice:

```
IN: df.merge(new_values, how='inner')
OUT:   ageGroup first2DigitsOfPostcode lookup_join_value valueOfProduct
0         1                     12               foo            low
1         1                     12               baz            low
```

Certainly shorter than the other answer I gave! I'll leave the old one though in case it inspires someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I think `df.isin()` is along the lines of what you're looking for.

Using your example df, and these two:

```
exists = pd.DataFrame({'ageGroup': [1],
                 'first2DigitsOfPostcode': ['12'],
                 'valueOfProduct' : 'low'})
new = pd.DataFrame({'ageGroup': [1],
                 'first2DigitsOfPostcode': ['12'],
                 'valueOfProduct' : 'high'})
```

Then you can check to see what values match, if all, or just some:

```
df.isin(exists.values[0])
Out[46]: ageGroup first2DigitsOfPostcode valueOfProduct 
0    True                   True           True 
1    False                  False          False
2    False                  True           False
3    True                   True           True

df.isin(new.values[0])
Out[46]: ageGroup first2DigitsOfPostcode valueOfProduct 
0    True                   True           False
1    False                  False          False
2    False                  True           True
3    True                   True           False
```

If your "query" wasn't a dataframe but instead a list it wouldn't need the ".values[0]" bit. The problem with a dictionary is it tries to match the index as well.

It's not clear to me from your question exactly what you want returned, but you could then subset based on whether all (or some) of the rows are the same:

```
# Returns matching rows    
df[df.isin(exists.values[0]).values.all(True)]

# Returns rows where the first two columns match
matches = df.isin(new.values[0]).values
df[[item==[True,True,False] for item in matches.tolist()]]
```

...There might be a smarter way to write that last one.

Comment: You are right. I was missing the returned lookup value. It is added `lookup_join_value ` in the latest edit

Comment: Df seems to work just as well. but only if df.isin(new_values) is used i.e. the other way round. So `df.drop('lookup_join_value', axis=1).isin(new_values)` would give me the right rows. But It is not yet clear for me how to filter the result correctly (only for the 3 named rows  = True) without just returning `NaN` in the lookup column value as caused by `df[df.drop('lookup_join_value', axis=1).isin(new_values)]`

Comment: What about: `mask = df.drop('lookup_join_value', axis=1).isin(new_values.values[0]).values.all(True)`. There might be a better way to pull the 'True' rows but this does work!

Comment: That is `TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: Hmm. It runs for me, but see my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

`df.query` is an option if you can write if can the query as and expression using the column names:

so you can do:

```
query_string = 'some long (but valid) boolean query'
```

example from pandas:

```
>>> from numpy.random import randn
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=list('ab'))
>>> df.query('a > b')
# similar to this
>>> df[df.a > df.b]
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Comment: This sounds interesting. But wouldn't I need to specify one such category for each lookup value? And as outlined in the edited question this would lead to some very messy / bad maintainable code of a lot of if else conditions. What I really want to compute is just a lookup of columns matching a (vector) of columns and if there is an exact match get the value from the lookup data frame.